# How to solve AJAX cross-domain problems with csrftoken

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I want to use the csrf_token to solve the Cross-domain problem about ajax, but I have some problems

here is my json :

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "distribution_box_id": "abc123", 
    "timestamp": "2019-07-11T07:00:00", 
    "lock1": 0, 
    "lock2": 0, 
    "temperature": 26.0, 
    "humidity": 10.0, 
    "latitude": 35.15409152643205, 
    "longitude": 109.45553839575084, 
    "smoke_detector": 0
}

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/app1/distributionboxdata/1',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Csrf-Token': '@play.filters.csrf.CSRF.getToken.map(_.value)'
    },
    data: {
        name: '@name'
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        location.reload();
    },//I don't know what to put here
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you make your code legible ... and what is your problem? an error in the console?

Comment: the console error is :Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/app1/distributionboxdata/1' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I try to use the csrf_token to solve the Cross-domain problem about ajax

Comment: Looks like you just need to fix the CORS headers on the server.

Comment: if your web page is loaded using `file:///` protocol, then you may not be able to fix CORS easily

Comment: would you please gave me an example? or do I need to solve the Cross-domain problem

Comment: do I need to solve the Cross-domain problem by using cors?

Answer (score 0):

Use To get get csrf token

```
 <script>
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        </script>
```

and in ajax call

```
     $.ajax({
                url: '/app1/distributionboxdata/1',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,

                headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')},

                success: function (data) {

                   console.log("");
                },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The API which you're calling should be cross-domain compatible. You need to set HTTP headers to allow making cross domain calls from the browser, else the browser will not allow to make this calls due to same origin policy. If you're trying to call this API from domain say 'hello.com', then at the server code of the API you should set the header of Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be 'hello.com' so that calls coming from this domain to the API is allowed. If you set it to * then any site can call this API which is not recommended.